# How to write a formula in Excel If a cell contains text1 OR text2 OR text3, return keyword1 with multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am really struggling to group my data. I have an Excel document with almost 500 rows of data and I wanted to bucket this into some keywords. I have a column which has different text values for each row, and I wanted to group these. May be best explained with an example:

EG:

| Status | Group |
| --- | --- |
| Completed | Closed/Completed |
| Suspended | Closed/Completed |
| Terminated | Closed/Completed |
| No longer available | Closed/Completed |
| Withdrawn | Closed/Completed |
| Not Yet Rec | Planned/Unknown |
| Unknown Status | Planned/Unknown |
| Ongoing | Open |
| Active, not rec | Open |
| REC | Open |

In the table above the column 'Status' is where I am searching for the data, and the column 'Group' is what I would like to be returned by a formula - based on the conditions.

What would be the quickest way to automate this for my spreadsheet?

I have tried many different formulae but this doesn't seem to work for bucketing.

In addition to this, I have a similar request for another column, maybe the same workaround/formula could be used here:

| Type | Group2 |
| --- | --- |
| Previously Treated Myelodysplastic Syndrome;Recurrent Adult Acute Myeloid Leukemia | Leukemia |
| AML | Leukemia |
| Recurrent Plasma Cell Myeloma;Refractory Plasma Cell Myeloma | Multiple Myeloma |
| MM | Multiple Myeloma |
| Acute T Cell Leukemia Lymphoma;Bone Cancer;Bone Metastases;Bone Neoplasm;Breast Neoplasms;Cancer;Malignancies;Malignancies Multiple;Malignant Glioma;Neoplasm Metastasis;Neoplasm of Bone;Neoplasm of Lung;Neoplasm, Breast;Neoplasms Pancreatic;Neoplasms,Colorectal;Pancreas Cancer;Pancreatic Adenocarcinoma;Pancreatic Cancer;Pancreatic Neoplasms;Refractory Cancer;Refractory Neoplasm;Refractory Non-Hodgkin Lymphoma;Renal Cancer;Resistant Cancer;Sarcoma | Lymphoma |
| Myelodysplastic Syndromes | Other |
| Acute Myelogenous Leukemia;AML | Leukemia |

etc.

For this table, I just want 1 of 4 options to be thrown out by the search of a keyword ( i know this can be done using wildcards)

So; if the column 'type' includes the words Lymphoma return Lymphoma, if includes MM OR Myeloma return Multiple Myeloma, if includes Leukemia OR AML return Leukemia, and for all else return 'Other'.

I have written this formula, but it doesn't work for all cells:

`=IF(COUNTIF(E431,"*Lymphoma*"),"Lymphoma",IF(COUNTIF(E431,"*Leukemia*"),"Leukemia",IF(COUNTIF(E431,"*AML*"),"Leukemia",IF(COUNTIF(E431,"*Myeloma*"),"Multiple Myeloma",IF(COUNTIF(E431,"*MM*"),"Multiple Myeloma","Other"))))`

This formula does not work for the last cell of the table above, it returns 'Other' when it should be returning 'Leukemia'.

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/excel-if-cell-contains-formulas/

I have followed the above article, specifically this section:

'If cell contains, then return value – multiple conditions
A single ‘if cell contains’ statement is easy, right? But what if you need to check multiple conditions in the same formula and return different results? That is, if a cell contains some text, then return something, if it contains another text, then return something else, and so on.

To evaluate multiple conditions in a cell, you can use nested "if cell contains" statements. This allows you to create a chain of checks, with each condition leading to a specific result.

Use the COUNTIF function to count how many times a certain text appears in a cell. If the count is greater than zero, then return the corresponding value. Otherwise, check the next condition.

[image]

So I need a solution like the one above, but to be able to handle multiple things.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Thank you in advance.

I have managed to fix the second problem with some adjusting to the above formula:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all who have provided answers, unfortunately I was not able to incorporate these into my work.

I have however found a workaround for both issues using IF(COUNTIF) statements:

To create column Group in table 1 I have done the following:

`=IF(SUM(COUNTIFS([@[Status]],{"*Completed*","*Suspended*","*Terminated*","*No longer*","*Withdrawn*"})),"Closed/Completed",IF(SUM(COUNTIFS([@[Status]],{"*Not yet*","*Unknown*"})),"Planned/Unknown", IF(SUM(COUNTIFS([@[Status]],{"*Ongoing*","*Active*","*Recruiting*"})),"Open","Other")))`

Which returns :

[image]

And for the second table, I have made some edits to the formula written so that it now reads multiple statements in the wildcard search. To create the column Group2 in the second table I have used:

`=IF(COUNTIF(E4,"*Lymphoma*"),"Lymphoma",IF(SUM(COUNTIFS(E4,{"*Leukemia*","*AML*"})),"Leukemia",IF(SUM(COUNTIFS(E4,{"*Myeloma*", "*MM*"})),"Multiple Myeloma","Other")))`

And this also then returns:

[image]

So my problem has been solved :) Hoping this helps if anyone has the same issue in the future.

Comment: I see why suggested formulae did not provide the answer you had in mind. You wanted to search for a combination of criteria to return something else, which was not as the question was asked, but this looks like a nice solution for your problem.

Comment: My apologies if I wasn’t able to articulate my problem in the best way; i did try and explain as best as i could - but my wording could have potentially been improved - english is my 2nd language and therefore sometimes it is difficult to expressed exactly what i want. I really do appreciate the time and effort put into proving an answer by yourself so thank you for that & I will try to ask questions better in the future. How should I have phrased my question to allow for others to better understand it? I don’t want to confuse anyone in future

Comment: Well the problem you encountered was: you wanted to return certain result in case the text consisted `A` or `B` argument. The current COUNTIF formula only checked for 1 argument at a time. So your question should've been about how to deal with that.

Comment: I edited an alternative way to accomplish the same, which may be better to read/maintain.

Answer (score 2):

```
=LET(list,{"Lymphoma","Leukemia","AML","Myeloma","MM"},
IFERROR(@TOCOL(IFS(ISNUMBER(FIND(list,A431)),list),2),"Other"))
```

This stores the names as `list` and @TOCOL returns the first non error of items found from the list inside your cell. If it's unlisted, it returns `"Other"`

Edit: given the logic from the answer, one could also formulate it like:

```
=IFNA( 
      IFS(
          COUNTIF(A431,"*Lymphoma*"),
             "Lymphoma",
          SUM(COUNTIFS(A431,{"*Leukemia*","*AML*"})),
             "Leukemia",
          SUM(COUNTIFS(A431,{"*Myeloma*","*MM*"})),
            "Multiple Myeloma"),
      "Other")
```

Comment: I still recommend using actual table for this, so it'll spill all over the table, also if you add a new record

Comment: Unfortunately this also does not provide what I am looking for. The best workaround that I found to the second issue, after relentless google searches was this:

`=IF(COUNTIF(E4,"*Lymphoma*"),"Lymphoma",IF(SUM(COUNTIFS(E4,{"*Leukemia*","*AML*"})),"Leukemia",IF(SUM(COUNTIFS(E4,{"*Myeloma*", "*MM*"})),"Multiple Myeloma","Other")))`

And I have dragged this down to auto populate all of the other cells. I have added a picture to my question of what this looks like.

Comment: So what doesn't work about it? (Or do you not have Office 365 maybe?). Also your picture doesn't show the problem you have with your "own" formula.

Comment: When I use your formula I get a warning message which alters the formula and then just puts 'Other' in all of the cells (I've added another image now). After changing my 'own' formula from the one pasted in the question, to the one in my comment this now provided me what I was looking for. I just wanted to say that I have troubleshooted using the IF(COUNTIF) statements.

Comment: I see you have the intersection operator wrong (`@`) this causes it to only look at the first value of the list. You could also use: `=LET(list,{"Lymphoma","Leukemia","AML","Myeloma","MM"},IFERROR(TAKE(TOCOL(IFS(ISNUMBER(FIND(list,A431)),list),2),1),"Other"))`

Answer (score 1):

For the Status / Group problem, I am not getting how the bucketing is supposed to work. Isn't this just an XLOOKUP?

```
=XLOOKUP( E431, Status, Group )
```

For the second case, perhaps you can do:

```
=IFERROR( INDEX( FILTER( Group2, ISNUMBER( FIND( E431,Type ) ) ), 1 ), "Other" )
```

Comment: So I don't actually have the columns for Group and Group2, these are what I want them to return. The tables above are a very small snippet of a large set of data with over 500 rows. 

The columns that actually exist in my data set are the 'Status' and 'Type' columns, whereas I want the solution/formula to pre-populate the new columns that I am to add (group and group1). I have only populated them here to show what I want the final result to look like based off of only having the one column. I hope that this makes sense.

Comment: Nice to see you on here again, Mark! @stayschemin If you make it an actual table and create a table with the lookup values, then suggested solution could work and is way more efficient. Maybe add the "Others" in the `if not found` parameter of XLOOKUP: `=XLOOKUP(Table1[Type],Tables[Status],Table2[Group],"Other")` or untested`=@FILTER(Group2,ISNUMBER(FIND(E431,Type)),"Other")`